# Polygon repour clearance rule

Tags: altium, clearance, polygon

I have some trouble editing a project, I had to replace some footprints on a board and thus rebuild polygon planes on top.

[image: Repoured polygon planes]

As you can see on the first picture, after rebuilding the polygon, the shape of the clearance between the shield guard and the red plane is not as it used to be (2nd picture is the original project). The shape of the polygon pour made me thaught that the rule is applied between the plane and the vias on the shield guard, but not between the shield guard and the plane.

[image: Polygon planes on original project]

I didnt modify any design rules so what's can go wrong here ?

[image: Clearance SGND (shield guard)]

[image: Polygon SGND]

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the result when you perform Right Click -> Polygon Actions -> Repour Selected ?

Comment: @RohatKılıç  Yes it is.

Comment: Then check the polygon connection style. I can't remember how the setting page are opened but probably not from the Rules page. Could be through "Preferences". Anyway. The first picture is an indication of a "Relief" connection style. When you change it to "Direct" style and repour the polygon then the vias will be fixed. I'm not sure about the big isolation barriers to the left, however, because there seem to be circular-shaped pads there.

Comment: The names have changed over the years, **via connect style**, **polygon connect style**, change it from thermal relief to direct, or solid.  Then force re-pour all the polygons.